# Compare table columns and display differences in error message in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write some SQL which will compare two SQL server tables and display any differences  in columns in an error message.  There could be multiple differences so I need each of these mentioned in the error message.  I've made a start on this but keen for some pointers on how I can capture exact differences.

Thanks,

```
SELECT      name, 
        object_id   
INTO        #sysTbl
FROM        sys.tables
ORDER BY    name

SELECT      t.name AS 't_name', 
            cols.name AS 'c_name', 
            cols.user_type_id,
            typ.name as user_type_name,
            cols.max_length,
            cols.is_nullable
INTO        #sysCols
FROM        #sysTbl t
INNER JOIN  sys.all_columns AS cols ON t.object_id = cols.object_id
INNER JOIN  sys.types AS typ ON cols.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id

    SELECT  *
    INTO #errorTbl
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    dbo.[metaDataFile] 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  *
        FROM    #sysCols
        UNION 
        SELECT  *
        FROM    #sysCols
        EXCEPT
        SELECT *
        FROM    dbo.[metaDataFile] 
    ) err

    DECLARE @errStr VARCHAR(MAX) 
    --build Error Message
    select @errStr = 'There is a mismatch on' + stuff((select ',' + ' table ' + t_name +' on column ' + c_name 
                FROM #errorTbl t2
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

        IF EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM #errorTbl
        )
                RAISERROR (@errStr, 
                   16, -- Severity,  
                   1, -- State,  
                   N'Failure due to data mismatch'); 
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Success - Data Matches'
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overly simplified but here's an effort using information schema:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG='DB NAME'
    and TABLE_NAME='TABLE NAME'
```

This will give all of the column info and metadata regarding the table in question.

Now try this for both:

```
select 
    t1.COLUMN_NAME
    ,DataType_NoMatch = case when t1.DATA_TYPE <> t2.DATA_TYPE then 1 else 0 end
from
    (
    select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_CATALOG='DB NAME'
        and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA'
        and TABLE_NAME='TABLE'
        ) t1
    join
    (
    select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_CATALOG='DBANME'
        and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA'
        and TABLE_NAME='TABLE2'
    ) t2 on t1.COLUMN_NAME=t2.COLUMN_NAME
```

and work your way through the attributes that you want to compare. I gave you an example for data type.

Added based on Cross apply comment:

```
select 
    t1.COLUMN_NAME
    ,ca.*
from
    (
    select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_CATALOG='DB NAME'
        and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
        and TABLE_NAME='DimOrganization'
        ) t1
    join
    (
    select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_CATALOG='DB NAME'
        and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bak'
        and TABLE_NAME='DimOrganization'
    ) t2 on t1.COLUMN_NAME=t2.COLUMN_NAME
cross apply
    (select Metadata = 'DataType' ,TestPassFail = case when t1.DATA_TYPE <> t2.DATA_TYPE then 1 else 0 end 
     union all
     select [Column] = 'CharMaxLen' ,TestPassFail = case when t1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <> t2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH then 1 else 0 end
     ) ca

where ca.TestPassFail=1
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now that I could potentially add something like this for each column                                                        CASE WHEN t1.datatype <> t2.datatype 
   THEN 'Table ' + t1.table_name +' on column '+ t1.column_name + ' has changed from '+ CAST(t1.datatype AS VARCHAR(20))  + ' to ' + CAST(t2.datatype_id AS VARCHAR(20))
 ELSE CAST('Unchanged'AS VARCHAR(10))                                    END AS datatypeMessage           but I'm not sure how I can only select those columns that are <> 'unchanged' so that I can pass these to an error message to flag as changes.

Comment: Instead of going columnar, you can unpivot using a cross apply.  Cross apply (select [your formula for test1] as test union all select [test2] ... where test <> 'unchanged') ca

Comment: @Jen I demonstrated what I meant by cross apply

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help on this KeithL

Comment: Would it be possible to loop through in the cross apply through the various column names i.e. data_type, character_max_length in the table instead of having to use for example Data_type multiple times in the select statement?  instead it would loop through the table and pass the column value into the select that way it would only write the select statement once?